# Merit does not create badge in DB using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, merit-gem

I have a rails app using devise, rails 4 and ruby 2.1.0. Devise is using the `user` model with `config.scoped_views = true`. I have followed the [this wiki](https://github.com/tute/merit/wiki/How-to-grant-badges-on-user-registration-using-Devise) for setting up merit using devise. When a user registers the badge is not added to the database - it does work if I manually add the badge in the `create` action using `current_user.add_badge('1')` and I can display the badge in a view. I have posted the relevant code below, if someone could tell me what I am missing? Merit offers awesome functionality and I would really like to get it working - thanks!

`app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    @user = build_resource # Needed for Merit
    super
  end

  def update
    @user = resource # Needed for Merit
    super
  end
end
```

`app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_merit

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
end
```

`app/models/merit/badge_rules.rb`

```
module Merit
  class BadgeRules
    include Merit::BadgeRulesMethods

    def initialize
      grant_on 'registrations#create', badge: 'just-registered', model_name: 'User'
    end
  end
end
```

`config/initializers/merit.rb`

```
Merit.setup do |config|
  config.checks_on_each_request = true
end

Badge.create!(
  id: 1,
  name: 'just-registered'
)
```

Comment: Try `grant_on 'users/registrations#create'` (add `users/`).

Comment: Great, that did the trick! I had originally tried `Users::RegistrationsController#create` but that did not work. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to create badge in case of confirmable feature